# MSSQL:Group data from multiple rows in 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to writing queries in SQL and looking for some tips

I ran a query that resulted in the table below:

| Company Name | Seller | Investor | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| App | SellerX | InvestorA | 01/01/2000 |
| App | SellerX | InvestorB | 01/01/2000 |
| Phone | SellerY | InvestorC | 09/08/2000 |
| Phone | SellerY | InvestorD | 09/08/2000 |
| Phone | SellerY | InvestorE | 09/08/2000 |

And I would like my results to look like this:

| Company Name | Seller | Investor | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| App | SellerX | InvestorA,InvestorB | 01/01/2000 |
| Phone | SellerY | InvestorC,InvestorD,InvestorE | 09/08/2000 |

Anyone can help on the best way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint:  `string_agg()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `string_agg` as follows:

```
Select company_name, seller,
       String_agg(investor, ',') within group (order by investor) as investor,
       Date
  From (your_query) t
 Group by company_name, seller, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using **STUFF**

```
SELECT companyname,seller,STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',' ,Investor) 
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.companyname = t2.companyname
AND t1.seller=t2.seller
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS Investor,date
From table t2
```